# How to embed an HTML file into a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

Is there anyway to embed an HTML file that is stored locally into a PowerPoint presentation?

I know I can paste the link in the presentation and then click the link to open it in the browser but I'm wondering if it is possible to actually render the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in the presentation itself?

To be clear I'm looking for a way to do this with a local HTML file without any 3rd party software or add-ins b/c strict IT regulations on my offices computers.

Answer (score 3):

You can't with PowerPoint by itself but there are add-ins such as LiveWeb:
http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm

LiveWeb is just one example and their website is pretty self explanitory how to use it.

In order to install an Add-In:

1. Click the Office button at the top left of PowerPoint, click PowerPoint Options, and then Add-Ins
2. In the Manager list, click Powerpoint Add-ins, then Go.
3. In the Add-Ins dialog, click Add New
4. In the Add New PowerPoint Add-In box browse for the one you wish to add (in this case wherever you saved LiveWeb to) and click OK
5. Click Enable Macros and then Close.

Comment: I saw this add-in somewhere as a solution to this similar problem on Quora or something. And I'm sure it's great but I'm working in an office where our computers are super-locked-down by IT so we can't go installing anything. I'm looking for a way to do this with a local HTML file without any 3rd party software. I appreciate the effort though and will up-vote for that.

Comment: It appears then it will not work with just PowerPoint. The closest you can get is an image of the site and then link the url to that image.

Comment: I understand that there is no conventional way to do this but I'm hoping that someone might know some kind of hack or workaround.

Comment: Have a look here:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291926/how-to-use-the-webbrowser-control-on-a-slide

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I tried this out of my own curiosity but got an error "This ActiveX control cannot be inserted". I looked and apparently this method is turned off by default "for security reasons". You also have to change a registry value to make it work: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2793374/cannot-insert-certain-scriptable-activex-controls-into-office-2013-documents

Comment: @EricF Yes, thanks for adding that.  I'd forgotten that MSNanny was going to declare that a no-no and make us wash our hands after touching it. ;-)